# Unhashable type

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# all ingredients, represented by numbers: 0= empty selection 1=rice 2=spice 3=vegetable 
allIng = [0,1,2,3]

#Each individual recipe(r)


# Veggie Rice Balls
r1 = (0,1,3)

# Curry Rice
r2 =(0,1,2)

# Herb Sauté
r3 = (0,2,3)

# Vegetable Curry
r4 = (1,2,3)


# all recipes on one list 

allRec = [r1,r2,r3,r4]
allRecNames = {(0,1,3): 'Veggie Rice Balls', (0,1,2): 'Curry Rice', (0,2,3): 'Herb Sauté', (1,2,3): 'Vegetable Curry'}


#ingredients picked
iP = []
#ingredient count
iC = 1

#User given option to pick up to 3 ingredients
while iC <= 3:
    pitem = int (input ("Pick up to 3 items "))

    if pitem in allIng:
        iP.append(pitem)
        print(iP)
        iC += 1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect entry, please pick again")

#sort list
iP.sort()
iP = tuple(iP)

#compare iP to allRec looking for matches
if iP in allRec:

    match = set ([iP]) & set(allRec)
    print ("Match:",match)
    allRecNames[match]
```

Hi all,

Trying to get my code to print out the name of the dishes that match to their respective match. For example, if I were to enter in 0,1,3, I would get back Veggie Rice Balls.

Currently getting error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Please correct me if I'm wrong and ELI5, but does it mean I need to convert match into something hashable before:

```
 allRecNames[match]
```

Someone here before recommended the tuple conversion in my code and thought I could do something similar here as well but getting no trail and error.

As always, any help is appreciated and sorry if this is a stupid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in your dictionary are tuples, so you need to use a tuple to access it. Fortunately, `iP` is a tuple, and you already know it's a key in the dictionary because that's what your `if` statement tests.

So, you just need to change `allRecNames[match]` to `allRecNames[iP]`.

That said, this line by itself does nothing; it just gets a value from the dictionary, but doesn't use that value for anything. You probably want to print it, so in that case it should be `print(allRecNames[iP])`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but wanted to say thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Answering the question in the title: try this before using it as a dictionary key:

```
match = frozenset(match)
```

The error reported means that `match` is a modifiable `set`, hence it cannot be used as a dictionary key. By using `frozenset` we make it immutable, so we can use it as a key.

Be aware though, that's not the real issue! `match` doesn't look like it contains the value you expect and that can be used as key for `allRecNames`. I did a quick example and it looks like this:

```
match
=> set([(1, 2, 3)])
```

But the keys in `allRecNames` look like this:

```
allRecNames.keys()
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3)]
```

Did you spot the problem? your `match` variable contains a set of a list of a tuple, but a key for `allRecNames` is just a tuple. Your code is broken by design - perhaps what you really, really meant was this:

```
if iP in allRec:
    allRecNames[iP]
```

Comment: @kaya3 you're right, I clarified my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you kind stranger. Truly appreciate the breakdown!